# How do I use literal quotes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, literals, double-quotes, single-quotes

This is my code:

```
const myFunction = () => {
   let winnerScreen="images/winner.png";
   let winnerId="winnerScreen";
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML='<img id='+winnerId+" "+'src='+winnerScreen+'/>';
}
```

I have a feeling that I'm able to write this function in one line, but I don't know how to use literal quotes in JavaScript.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: If you just added your code to the post as text ...

Comment: [`Template Literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: **Avoid screenshots** for code please.

Comment: I genuinely have trouble reading that code due to the bad contrast between it and the rest of the page.

Comment: you mean to write the function in one line?

Comment: I'm sorry for using screenshots, it's my first post on this forum and didn't know this was a rule, I will do in my next posts.

Comment: You can edit your post and make it follow the rules now. No need to wait for your next question. Voting to close this.

Comment: You can still edit your current question. Putting the actual code takes less effort than having a screenshot. It also helps out anybody who wants to help you, since they can just copy and paste it in their answer and make changes.

Answer (score 1):

this would be an one-liner with a template literal:

```js
const myFunction = () => document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = `<img id='${"winnerScreen"}' src='${"images/winner.png"}' />'`;


myFunction();
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

But in that case it does not make sense to use a template literal as you could simply pass the strings..

```js
const myFunction = () => document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "<img id='winnerScreen' src='images/winner.png' />";

myFunction();
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

NOTE:

- You can write the string by using `"` and `'` quotes (like in the last snippet):

  `"<img id='winnerScreen' src='images/winner.png' />"`
- or only a single quote type like `'` and use string escaping `\'` looks like follows:

  `'<img id=\'winnerScreen\' src=\'images/winner.png\' />'`

Answer (score 1):

With new versions, you can use backticks (`) and work more or less like in PHP, using interpolation:

`` document.getElementById("output").innerHTML= `<img id="${winnerId}" src="${winnerScreen}">` ``

Please be aware that:

- attributes should be enclosed in double quotes`
- please **avoid using screenshots for code**.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just a beginner on this forum, will take notes! :) And thanks you for the help.

Comment: "*attributes should be enclosed in double quotes* " - single quotes are also fine - https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Do like this.Use backtick & `$`

```js
let winnerId = 1;
let winnerScreen = 'https://unknownSource.com/uk.jpg'
var _str = `<img id = "${winnerId}" src ="${winnerScreen}">`;
console.log(_str)
```

Comment: If I try this it says the following error message: "String templates are not supported by current JavaScript version". I'm using WebStorm 2017.2.4 with ECMAScript 5.1, Should I update to ECMAScript 6 or is there any reason no to?

Comment: You need to change the js vesrion ecma6 from webstrom

Answer (score 0):

Write a string literal like:

```
document.getElementById('output').innnerHTML = `<img id=${winnerId} src=${winnerScreen} />`;
```

But it's better to put `"` around HTML attributes:

```
document.getElementById('output').innnerHTML = `<img id="${winnerId}" src="${winnerScreen}" />`;
```

Or if you want the whole function to be on one line:

```
const myfunction = () => document.getElementById('output').innnerHTML = '<img id="images/winner.png" src="winnerScreen" />';
```

But that's a bit silly, don't try to conserve lines, try to conserve *code readability* instead.

Comment: It would still cost me 3 lines though, is there any way I could do it in one line?

Comment: What do you mean? That's only one line. There's not really any way to condense the code any further, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I think he wants to have the function as an one-liner

Comment: Yes the whole function as one line :) is that possible?

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks a lot for the help and knowledge! :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you mean is how to use quotes in quotes.

You have 2 versions of quotes.

`"` and `'`.

Inside each one you can use the other.

```
document.getElementByID('output').innerHTML = "<img id='winnerScreen' src='images/winner.png'>";
```

Comment: I was wondering why all the other answers were about template literals when this is already there and easier to do. I just like to add that you can also escape quotes - `"this is a string with \"quoted\" text"` - also works with both types of quotes.

Comment: Because there are variables involved and your answer is completely ignoring this fact.

Comment: @Cranio Hint was one line. Perhaps he does — not — want variables. I was — not — able to comment yet. And am — not — now.

Comment: @Cranio the question doesn't make it apparent that the variables are *needed*. All it says is that it needs that code to be on one line which it would be if you remove the variables. If you use a template literal you *still* need the variables, so it's not going to be a single line. Otherwise there is no real reason *not* to use a simple string. The question, as it stands, cannot really be interpreted as "how do I include variables in a string" - it literally just mentions quotes.